# Area - Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking at the following exercise:

Let $S$ be the torus $$\sigma (\theta, \phi)=((a+b\cos\theta )\cos \phi , (a+b\cos \theta )\sin \phi , b\sin\theta)$$ Describe the parts $S^+$ and $S^−$ of $S$ where the Gaussian curvature $K$ of $S$ is positive and negative, respectively. Show, without calculation, that

$$\iint_{S^+}K d\mathcal{A} = −\iint_{S^−}K d\mathcal{A} = 4\pi$$

$$$$

I have done the following:

$$K=\frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F^2}=\frac{\cos \theta}{b(a+b\cos\theta)}$$

Since $0<b<a$ we have that $a+b\cos\theta>0$.

Therefore, $$K>0 \Leftrightarrow \cos\theta>0 \Leftrightarrow 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2} \land \frac{3\pi}{2}<\theta<2\pi$$ 
and 
$$K<0 \Leftrightarrow \cos\theta<0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

So, $$S^+=\{(\theta, \phi) \mid 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2} \land \frac{3\pi}{2}<\theta<2\pi, 0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi\}$$ and $$S^-=\{(\theta, \phi) \mid \frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}, 0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi\}$$

Is this correct?

$$$$

In a previous exericse I have shown the following:

Let $\sigma : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a patch of a surface $S$. The image under the Gauss map of the part $\sigma (R)$ of $S$ corresponding to a region $R \subseteq U$ has area
$$\iint_R
|K|d\mathcal{A}σ,$$
where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of $S$.

$$$$

Is it maybe as follows?

$$\iint_S |K|d\mathcal{A}=\iint_{S^+} Kd\mathcal{A}-\iint_{S^-} Kd\mathcal{A}$$

How could we continue to get the desired result?

$$$$

According to

$$\iint_{S^+}|K|d\mathcal{A}$$ is the area of the image under the Gauss map of the part $\sigma (S^+)$ corresponding to a region $S^+$.

The image under the Gauss map is the values of $\textbf{N}$ at the points of $S$.

So is maybe the image under the Gauss map in this case a surface of which the area is known?

Comment: You better parametrize $S_{+}$ as $\{ ( \theta, \phi ) : |\theta| < \pi/2, \phi \in [0,2\pi) \}$, the normal map $N$ is a **bijection** between the part corresponding to $S_{+}$ on the torus and the unit sphere excluding the north and south poles.

Comment: How do we get that $|\theta |<\frac{\pi}{2}$ ? Isn't the interval of $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ ? How do we get then $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ ? Could you explain to me further why $N$ is that bijection? @achillehui

Comment: For any $(\theta,\phi) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the map $\sigma$ defines a parametrization of  the torus on some neighborhood of $\sigma(\theta,\phi)$. The choice of domain $[0,2\pi] \times [0,2\pi]$ is only one of them. The problem is in this parametrization, the description of $S_{+}$ isn't that clean. About $N$, the normal at $\sigma(\theta,\phi)$ is $(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta)$. This provides a parametrization of the unit sphere ( same as (latitude, longitude) for earth or ( declination, right ascension) for sky).

Comment: I got it!! Is $$\iint_S |K|d\mathcal{A}=\iint_{S^+} Kd\mathcal{A}-\iint_{S^-} Kd\mathcal{A}$$ correct? Or should it be "plus" instead of "minus" ?  @achillehui

Comment: Isn't it $$N=(-\cos\theta \cos\phi, -\cos\theta\sin\phi , -\sin\theta)$$ Or have I calculated it wrong? @achillehui

Comment: It depends out how you define your normal, I'm refering to the outward normal pointing towards the unbound component of $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S$

Comment: I used the formula $$N=\frac{\sigma_u\times\sigma_v}{\|\sigma_u\times\sigma_v\|}$$ Is this correct? @achillehui

Comment: This is one way to define normal vector. Depends on the orientation of your parametrization, you can get the outward or inward pointing normals. As long as you are consistent in their usage, both are fine.

Comment: So, we have that this $N$ is a sphere for the values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ of $S^+$, right? @achillehui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the Gauss-Bonnet theorem then, you know that

$$
0= 4\pi*(2-2g) =\iint_S K \;\mathrm{d}\mathcal{A} = \iint_{S^+} K \;\mathrm{d}\mathcal{A}+\iint_{S^-} K \;\mathrm{d}\mathcal{A},
$$

thus,

$$
\iint_{S^+} K \;\mathrm{d}\mathcal{A}= -\iint_{S^-} K \;\mathrm{d}\mathcal{A}.
$$

We also know from Gauss-Bonnet that,

$$
\iint_{S^+}K \; \mathrm{d}\mathcal{A} = \int_{\delta S^+} \kappa_g \mathrm{d}\mathcal{s},
$$

where $\kappa_g$ is the geodesic curvature, but the boundary of $S$ is two circles along which $K\equiv0$. (We know this since $K$ switches sign here). Thus, these circles are asymptotic lines, and the geodesic curvature is just the curvature of the circles. Since the total curvature of a circle is $2\pi$ and there are two of them, we are done.

EDIT: $\sigma(S^{+})$ is a sphere a radius 1. The normal traces out a circle along the "equator" of the torus that corresponds to the equator of the sphere, and for every point on this circle it traces out a perpendicular circle (half on each side of the torus). This is easy to understand if you just think of the directions that the normals point in. (And the radius is 1 since $|N|=1$).

EDIT 2: You can think of $S^+$ as a sphere with a pair of antipodal points poked out, and then stretched along its equatorial plane.

EDIT 3: If you're allowed to compute $N$, then the field of normals is clearly a unit sphere when restricted to $S^+$ or $S^-$.

If you're not allowed to compute $N$, then consider the (non-regular) torus with $a=0$, this is clearly just a sphere of radius $b$ when restricted to $S^+$ or $S^-$. You know that the Gauss map of this sphere is a sphere of radius 1.

Now consider $\sigma$ restricted to $S^+$. If you scale $a$ and $b$ simultaneously, then the Gauss map will remain unchanged since it is scale invariant.

Since $\sigma$ is continuous as a function of $a$ and $b$, the Gauss map approaches a unit sphere (which does not depend on $b$) as $a\to 0$. This means that $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta$ s.t. $a\in B_\delta(0), b\in \mathbb{R^+} \Rightarrow |N -\sigma| < \epsilon$. But since the Gauss map is scale invariant, you can choose $a$ in the $\delta$-ball and any $b$ you want and then just scale to get any pair for $a$ and $b$ that yield Gauss maps that are arbitrarily close to a unit sphere so $\epsilon$ can be as large as you want. This implies that $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R^+}$ the Gauss map is constant. In particular it is the same as it is for $a=0$ which is the unit sphere.

Comment: We haven't done the Gauss-Bonnet theorem in class... Is this the only way to calculate it?

Comment: I just edited the answer to explain that the image under the Gauss map of $S^+$ is a sphere of radius 1.

Comment: Could you explain to me further why the image under the Gauss map of $S^+$ is a sphere of radius $1$ ? I haven't really understood that...

Comment: Considering $S^+$. The values of $N$ at $S^+$ "form" a unit sphere? Do we see that because of the interval of $\theta$ in $S^+$ that it is a sphere?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it means to "show without calculation". I have a feeling that this means without directly computing the integral. If you compute the value of $N$, then it is immediately clear that $N$ as a function of $\phi$ and $\theta$ is just a unit sphere for $(\phi, \theta)\in S^+$.

Comment: I see... And the same happens for $S^-$, i.e., $N$ as a function of $\phi$ and $\theta$ is a unit sphere for $(\phi, \theta )\in S^-$, right?

Comment: Yeah, I also added an explanation that requires zero calculation although it's a little complicated.

Comment: I think that it is alowed to compute $N$. So we have that $$\int_{S^+}|K|=\int_{S^+}K=\text{ area of unit sphere }=4\pi$$ 
$$\int_{S^-}|K|=-\int_{S^-}K=\text{ area of unit sphere }=4\pi$$ right?

Comment: Yup that's right.